# Find most similar words to randomy initialized array

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, gensim, word2vec

Using the Gensim package, I have trained a word2vec model on the corpus that I am working with as follows:

```
word2vec = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count = 3, size = 512, sg = 1)
```

Using Numpy, I have initialized a random array with the same dimensions:

```
vector = (rand(512)-0.5) *20
```

Now, I would like to find the words from the word2vec that are most similar to the random vector that I initialized.

For words in the word2vec, you can run:

```
word2vec.most_similar('word')
```

And the output is a list with most similar words and their according distance.

I would like to get a similar output for my initialized array.

However, when I run:

```
word2vec.most_similar(vector)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-297-3815cf183d05>", line 1, in <module>
    word2vec.most_similar(vector)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 1461, in new_func1
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\base_any2vec.py", line 1383, in most_similar
    return self.wv.most_similar(positive, negative, topn, restrict_vocab, indexer)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py", line 549, in most_similar
    for word, weight in positive + negative:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

What can I do to overcome this error and find the most similar words to my arrays?

I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273077/cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object-python3-opencv) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59357940/typeerror-cannot-unpack-non-iterable-numpy-float64-object) page. However, it is unclear to me how I could solve my problem with these suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gensim's `KeyedVectors` interface `.most_similar()` method **can** take raw vectors as its target, but in order for its current (at least through `gensim-3.8.3`) argument-type-detection to not mistake a single vector for a list-of-keys, you would need to provide it explicitly as one member of a list of items for the named `positive` parameter.

Specifically, this should work:

```py
similars = word2vec.wv.most_similar(positive=[vector,])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to see if a floating point number is similar to a string, and that doesn't work (`cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object`).

What you need to do is to properly generate **random strings**, not random floating point numbers. Once this is done, your code will work. See also the documentation that states `list of str` (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.most_similar)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Matthieu. Based on the documentation that you sent, it is not clear to me how I can generate a random string as I see `list of str` appearing quite frequently in the documentation. Could you provide an example of that?

Comment: You can create one by drawing a string size and then a random integer between 0 and 26 for each letter, that should give you your words.

Comment: There's no use in looking up random strings in a `Word2Vec` model, or the set of word-vectors it has created (and holds in its `.wv` property). They are overwhelmingly likely to generate a `KeyError`. But it is possible to use a raw vector, such as the random-position `vector` given in the question, as the origin point for a set of `.most_similar()` results, as detailed in my sibling answer.